# Access array elements by array/list of column indexes

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2D array of integers (e.g. A with A.shape (10,5)) and 1D array of column indexes (which generally differ among each other) (e.g. idx with idx.shape (10,)). From i-th row, I would like to acquire the element from array A with column index idx[i]. What would be the best (fastest) solution if the desired output is 1D array of acquired elements or list of those elements?

```
A = np.arange(50).reshape(10,5)
idx=np.array([2,4,0,0,3,1,3,1,2,4])
```

Desirable output:

```
output = [2,9,10,15,23,26,33,36,42,49]
```

or

```
output = np.array([2,9,10,15,23,26,33,36,42,49])
```

Comment: can you writte some code you have with your structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `numpy` you can take the diagonal of a column index, eg:

```
np.diag(A[:,idx])
# array([ 2,  9, 10, 15, 23, 26, 33, 36, 42, 49])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate` to access the row number you are on, and then use that to access the index you need on `idx` like so:

```
output = []

for row in enumerate(A):
    output.append(row[1][idx[row[0]]])
```

From this I got `output == [2, 9, 10, 15, 23, 26, 33, 36, 42, 49]`

Answer (score 2):

```
A[np.arange(A.shape[0]), idx]
```

`np.diag(A[:,idx])` works, but does more work than necessary.  `A[:,idx]` is a (10,10)`array (in this example), which is then whittled down to a`(10,)`.

For this small array, mine is 2x faster.  For a `(100,50)` it is 16x faster.